# _prepareCollection with product_options of sales_flat_order_item

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i am Trying to add Product_Options data on my Order Grid.
i extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('product_options', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Image'),
        'index' => 'product_options',
        'width' => '70',
        'renderer'=> new Ips_CustomizeOrder_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data()
    ));
    $this->addColumnsOrder('product_options', 'shipping_name');
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

protected function _prepareCollection() {

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $collection->getSelect()->join(
             'sales_flat_order_item',
             '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
             array('product_options')
           )->group('sales_flat_order_item.entity_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

i just get Image Column on Grid but data is blank, i have also checked table **sales_flat_order_item** where actual data is exists.

Answer (score 0):

it was just silly mistake. **sales_flat_order_item** Table create Two entry for configure products one for simple that is associate to configure and one is parent, which is main configure product.
All you have to do is

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item',
            '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
            array('product_options'))
            ->where('`sales_flat_order_item`.parent_item_id IS NULL')
            ->group('sales_flat_order_item.order_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
}
```

help from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61231/double-entries-appearing-when-adding-custom-attribute-to-orders-grid

One More important thing do not use **parent::_prepareCollection();** after your _prepareCollection. invoking this function will overwrite whatever you made collection change. Tested on Magento-1.9